# how to send EOF over socket in java

Tags: java, html, sockets

basically a html file that request for an image from the server and i've create a server that does the response stuff, but when the html request for the image the server sends the image completely but the client browser stays at loading the image and says "transferring data from Server", i had my research all over the internet and i found that i could be done just by closing the connection, but it didn't worked for me.

here is the code for my Server build in java:

```
package lesson1;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.Exception;

public class SecClass{

BufferedReader fd;
String  link = null, HTMLData = null, WEBROOT = "D:/PDT1";
String ptr = null, directory = null,
        GET_HEAD_POST = null, Protocol = null;
ServerSocket SRVSOCK;
Socket SOCK;
DataOutputStream dOut;
DataInputStream dInput;
InputStreamReader IR;


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    SecClass SERVER = new SecClass();
    SERVER.run();
}

public void run() throws Exception
{
    SRVSOCK = new ServerSocket(80);
    while(true){
        SOCK = SRVSOCK.accept();
        new Thread(new SocketThread(SOCK)).start();
    }
}

public class SocketThread implements Runnable {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Socket socket;

    public SocketThread(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            dOut = new DataOutputStream(SOCK.getOutputStream());
        }catch(Exception ie){
            System.out.println("Cound'nt create dOut");
        }

        try{
            IR = new InputStreamReader(SOCK.getInputStream());
        }catch(Exception ie){
            System.out.println("Cound'nt create IR");
        }


        BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR);
        String MESSAGE = null;
        System.out.println("Received Request!");
        try{
            MESSAGE = BR.readLine();

        }catch(Exception ie){
            System.out.println("Cound'nt Receive Message");
        }
        System.out.println(MESSAGE);

        if(MESSAGE != null && MESSAGE.contains("HTTP/")){
            Protocol = MESSAGE.substring(MESSAGE.length()-8);
            System.out.println("Request protocol is " + Protocol);
        } else {
            System.out.println("It's a Not HTTP request");
        }

        if(MESSAGE != null && MESSAGE.contains("GET ")){
            GET_HEAD_POST = "GET ";
            System.out.println("Reqest is GET");
            ptr = MESSAGE.substring(4);
            directory = ptr.substring(0,ptr.length()-9);
            link = ptr.substring(ptr.length() - 10);
            System.out.println(link);

        } else if(MESSAGE != null && MESSAGE.contains("HEAD ")){
            System.out.println("Request is HEAD");
            GET_HEAD_POST = "HEAD ";
            ptr = MESSAGE.substring(5);
            directory = ptr.substring(0,ptr.length()-9);
            link = ptr.substring(ptr.length() - 10);
        } else if(MESSAGE != null && MESSAGE.contains("POST ")){
            System.out.println("Request is POST");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Cound'nt verify request");
            try{
                SRVSOCK.close();
            }catch(Exception ie){
                System.out.println("Could not close SRVSOCK");
            }
            try{
                SOCK.close();
            }catch(Exception ie){
                System.out.println("Could not close SOCK");
            }

        }

        if(MESSAGE == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Unknown request");
            try{
                SOCK.close();
            }catch(Exception ie){
                System.out.println("Could not close SOCK");
            }

        } else {
            if((link.charAt(0)) == '/' && link != null){
                link = WEBROOT + directory + "index.html";
                try{

                    OpenFile();
                    dOut.close();
                    SOCK.close();
                    System.out.println("Came out of Openfile Func");

                }catch(Exception ie){
                    System.out.println("Could not Call for OpenFile Function");
                }
                try{
                    MESSAGE = BR.readLine();
                }catch(Exception ie){
                    System.out.println("Could not Receive message");
                }

                System.out.println(MESSAGE);

            } else {
                System.out.println("User Requested for a file");
                System.out.println(directory);

                link = WEBROOT + directory;
                try{
                    OpenFile();
                    dOut.close();
                    SOCK.close();
                }catch(Exception ie){
                    System.out.println("Could not Call for OpenFile Function");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
public void OpenFile() throws Exception{
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(link))) {
        String line;
        System.out.println("Request Link is: " + link);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            dOut.writeBytes(line);
        }
        dOut.flush();
        dOut.close();
        SOCK.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(link);
        dOut.writeBytes("<html><h1>404 File Not Found</h1></html>");
        System.out.println("File Does not Exist");

    }
}
}
```

and here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header> 
        <div class="HeaderBox">
            <img src="logo.png" alt="image" class="logoBox"/>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see i have tried twice to close connection on server when the image fully is transferred, but in my browser it stuck in loading and at bottom it say transferring data from 127.0.0.1

Comment: can you post your log messages as well?

Comment: yeah "Received Request!
GET /logo.png HTTP/1.1
Request protocol is HTTP/1.1
Reqest is GET
g HTTP/1.1
User Requested for a file
/logo.png
Request Link is: D:/PDT1/logo.png"
 and there is a bit while reading line by line and outputing it

Comment: can you move all fields except ServerSocket SRVSOCK;
Socket SOCK; from class SecClass to class SocketThread . Now try testing and tell the status

Comment: okay now in client browser it finishes receiving image but doesn't show it out in the browser, it just show the alt="" of the image

Answer (score 0):

First of all move all the fields except ServerSocket SRVSOCK; from class SecClass to class SocketThread. Make the Socket SOCK; a local reference in the run() method. Reason being your code is using multithreading. Therefore move them to SocketThread class. Also move OpenFile() for cleaner approach.

You are using same SOCK reference for different thread requests. And also while closing you refer to the SOCK field. This is the cause for erroneous behaviour. What could and mostly happens is one thread closes the socket of another thread because of incorrect SOCK referencing.

What you need to do is :

```
public void run() throws Exception
{
SRVSOCK = new ServerSocket(8088);
while(true){
    Socket SOCK;
    SOCK = SRVSOCK.accept();
    new Thread(new SocketThread(SOCK)).start();
}
}
```

And within SocketThread don't reference using SOCK .
Eg.
  `SOCK.getInputStream()` . change to `socket.getInputStream()` which is using the field of SocketThread. Change others similarly.

As for why image is not getting rendered:
Change OpenFile() to :

```
public void OpenFile() throws Exception{
    try (FileInputStream br = new FileInputStream (link)) {
        System.out.println("Request Link is: " + link);
        int i;
        while ((i = br.read()) > -1)
            dOut.write(i);

           dOut.flush();
            dOut.close();
            SOCK.close();
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(link);
            dOut.writeBytes("<html><h1>404 File Not Found</h1></html>");
            System.out.println("File Does not Exist");

        }
}
```

Change is basically to read the file in byte form and write it as bytes to the response stream. Whereas what was happening in your case was you were reading it as string.

You can check the [link](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/04/difference-between-fileinputstream-and-filereader-in-java.html) for difference between reading a file using reader vs inputstream.

Works for me. Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: yeah, it worked just perfect, one more thing why  does it just works on firefox but in chrome the server output Request received and nothing more. and thanks for you help

Comment: sorry, i can vote my reputation has not reached 15 yet, and please read my comment up their agian

Comment: there is some problem with the code regarding socket connections.. if you try in incognito mode. everything works perfect. try it out

Comment: okay that worked, but could specify which part of the code got the problem  so i could try to fix it?

Comment: Consider the fact that you showed how to CLOSE a socket, but didn't explain how to send EOF over the network THROUGH THE SOCKET.

The problem is that, multiple files can be sent, and EOF is a file separator.